# Is an intermediate List eligible for Garbage Collection when toStream is used?

Tags: scala, stream, garbage-collection

Let's say I want to create a `List[(Int, Int)]`:

```
scala> (0 to 3).toList.zip(0 to 3)
res3: List[(Int, Int)] = List((0,0), (1,1), (2,2), (3,3))
```

However, what if I wanted to create a `Stream[(Int, Int)]` instead:

```
scala> (0 to 3).toList.zip(0 to 3).toStream
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[(Int, Int)] = Stream((0,0), ?)
```

Is the intermediate list that was used to build `res4` eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: Why not just start with a Stream instead of a List: `(0 to 3).toStream.zip((0 to 3))`

Comment: I think in real case first or second collection is not generated - so we still have problem List.toStream or Stream.zip(_: List). Anyway, collection's tails (regardless of its implementation) will be captured until stream iterated (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

If consider list as object containing list's head + link to the tail, the answer is yes.

According to sources, there is no closures to input list inside created stream, so this list (which really is just "::" case class) can be collected. But list's tail (remaining chain of "::"'s) is captured inside closure (var tlGen) until you iterate over stream.

```
override def toStream : Stream[A] =
    if (isEmpty) Stream.Empty
    else new Stream.Cons(head, tail.toStream)

final class Cons[+A](hd: A, tl: => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A] {
    override def isEmpty = false
    override def head = hd
    @volatile private[this] var tlVal: Stream[A] = _
    @volatile private[this] var tlGen = tl _
    def tailDefined: Boolean = tlGen eq null
    override def tail: Stream[A] = {
      if (!tailDefined)
        synchronized {
          if (!tailDefined) {
            tlVal = tlGen()
            tlGen = null
          }
        }

      tlVal
    }
}
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala
https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala#L1223

So, all tails will be eligible for collection when stream will have fully iterated.

For example, let's take List(1, 2, 3, 4).toStream.foreach(_ => {}) :

```
stream iteration    captured tail     generated stream        eligible for GC
0                   List(2, 3, 4)     Stream(1, ?)            List(1, 2, 3, 4)
1                   List(3, 4)        Stream(1, 2, ?)         List(2, 3, 4)
2                   List(4)           Stream(1, 2, 3, ?)      List(3, 4)
3                   Nil               Stream(1, 2, 3, 4)      List(4)
```